# jquery Autocomplete - passing additional option value from form

Tags: jquery

I have 2  selectable option values for a keywords field ie Search for Keywords Option(int)1 or Name. option int(2)

I need to pass this addition option value along with the $q query to the search form.

How do i do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the extraParams option.  here's an example:

```
    jQuery("#InvestorName").autocomplete('<%= Url.Action("Autocomplete", "DocMgmt") %>', {
        dataType: 'json',
        extraParams: { type: "InvestorName" },
        max: 20,
        width: 355,
        matchContains: "word",
        autoFill: false,
        parse: function(data)
        {
            var rows = new Array();
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                rows[i] = { data: data[i], value: data[i].InvestorId, result: data[i].InvestorName };
            return rows;
        },
        formatItem: function(row, i, max)
        {
            return i + "/" + max + " [" + row.InvestorName + "]" + " (id: " + row.InvestorId + ")";
        },
        formatMatch: function(row, i, max)
        {
            return row.InvestorName + " " + row.InvestorId
        },
        formatResult: function(row)
        {
            return row.InvestorName;
        }
    }).result(function(event, data, formatted)
    {
        jQuery('#InvestorId').val(formatted);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks CurlyFro , want I need to do is collect the option using $_GET as im using it to change a SQL statement.

Comment: That did the trick thanks. extraParams (default value: {})
  Extra parameters for the backend. If you were to specify { bar:4 }, the
  autocompleter would call my_autocomplete_backend.php?q=foo&bar=4 (assuming
  the input box contains "foo").